# invincible, he has become

Tags: fronting

a. Invincible, he is.

b. Invincible, he has become.

Are the above sentences both grammatically correct?

I know they are not particularly natural. I think they can be used in certain contexts for effect and emphasis, especially if the word 'invincible' had been pronounced before, e.g.

c. He said he wanted to become invincible. Well, invincible he has become.

The sentences sound fine with 'invincible' but sound less good with an adjective like 'good'. I think they'd still be grammatical though.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Speak-Like-Yoda

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on all counts. The sentences, though not very natural, are perfectly correct and could be used in situations like your last example.